# Graphical model of the Gaussian mixture: where is n?

Tags: gaussian-mixture-distribution, hierarchical-bayesian, dirichlet-process, markov-random-field

TL;DR: Where are the occupation numbers in the Graphical model of the GMM?

I am implementing a Finite (to be adapted to infinite later) Gaussian Mixture Model. I am using the Gibbs sampler-ready formulations of [Yu 2009](https://yuxiaodong.files.wordpress.com/2009/09/derivation_of_gibbs_sampling_gmm1.pdf) and [Rasmussen 2000](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=0C2E4669A79911E0E9B5F8C123DFA97D?doi=10.1.1.45.9111&rep=rep1&type=pdf) as shown below: [image: Yu 2009 Graphical model]

However, I've noticed that $n_j$, the number of observations per cluster is not included in this depiction.

Looking at equation 4.4, I can see that $p(c_1,...c_i|\pi_i...\pi_k) = \prod_{j=1}^n \pi_j^{n_j}$ (incidentally, the notation for this expression differs between the papers and is quite confusing when trying to derive it yourself).

So each indicator variable $c$ (where $c_i=j$ indicates that datum $i$ belongs to the $j$th cluster) has a multinomial  distribution over $j$, which is dependent on the size $n_j$ of the cluster itself along with its weight $\pi_j$.

I don't understand why $n_j$ is ignored since when you sample from/fit this model you don't know how many data points belong to each cluster. Where would it fit and what prior does it have? I would guess that the vector $n$ would make another node directed at $c$.

But then Rasmussen introduces a conditional on $n_j|\alpha$ in equation 15.

This question is especially important to me because I require setting my own prior on the total number of data points $N$ which will then influence $\pi$ etc.

Comment: If the vector of the $c_i$'s is known, the statistics $n_j$, &tc. can be derived in a deterministic manner.

Comment: ah ok, thats obvious in the model above in hindsight. If there is a prior on total N, that can be a new node that doesn't join to pi/c.